# How can I recursively remove all json files with Git?

Tags: git

My project contains hundred of directories and subdirectories and I would like to remove all JSON files from git but keep them in the project

I tried

```
git rm -r ./*.json
```

but it's only removed the JSON files from the current directory. Is there a way to recursively remove them from all directories?

Answer (score 1):

Have fun:

```
find . -name "*json" | xargs git rm
```

I assume you've backed up the json files.

- The `find` command will find all the files ending in json, it includes the ones in subdirectories.
- The pipe `|` is a way to send those results the the next command.
- To paraphrase wikipedia: `xargs` converts input from standard input (the pipe) into arguments to a command, which is `git rm` in this case.

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Git itself supports recursive globbing via the pathspec.

```
git rm ':(glob)./**/*.json'
```

In this case, it's `git`, not the shell, that's expanding the pattern. `git rm './**/*.json'` would look for a literal file named `./**/*.json` to remove; the `:(glob)` enables pattern matching.

For more information, see the entry for "pathspec"  in `man gitglossary`.

If you want to remove the files from the repository only (but not the files in the current working directory), add the `--cached` option to the command:

```
git rm --cached ':(glob)./**/*.json'
```